# How to retrieve the value from local exe file

Tags: powershell

I've got the file "updates.exe", which runs a program. When this file is executed, I might see the next info:

Program Started 101.0.4951.41 version. etc.

How to get the version value '101.0.4951.41' ?

I need to put it to a variable and use it in my further actions.

$CurrentVersion = 101.0.4951.41
Like this.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `(Get-Item updates.exe).VersionInfo.FileVersionRaw`, which gives you a `System.Version` object. Note that `.VersionInfo.FileVersion` is not reliable, because it's just a string and not always consistent compared to the numeric version numbers stored in `FileVersionRaw`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately it doesn't solve my issue. Imagine that text inside this program is just a string. Like "Version is 12345" and I need to retrieve just 12345 from it. Any ideas?

Comment: In other words, I just need to retrieve third word with version from this text, because it's dynamically changed.

Comment: I see. Is `updates.exe` a console app or a GUI app? If it is a console app, try this: `$currentVersion = if((.\updates.exe | Out-String) -match '\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+'){ $matches.Value }`